# How do I insert date in YYYY-MM -DD HH24:MI:SS in Oracle

Tags: oracle

How do I insert date in YYYY-MM -DD HH24:MI:SS format in Oracle

Comment: [Date](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/Data-Types.html#GUID-5405B652-C30E-4F4F-9D33-9A4CB2110F1B) has no format: "The DATE data type stores date and time information. Although date and time information can be represented in both character and number data types, the DATE data type has special associated properties. **For each DATE value**, Oracle stores the following information: year, month, day, hour, minute, and second."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
INSERT INTO TABLE (COL1, ...) VALUES (
    to_date('2001-12-30 17:27:59', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS')
);
```

You submit a string and the date format to TO_DATE, and then use that in your VALUES clause of a TABLE INSERT command.

Oracle stores it as a DATE, there is no stored format of the date. When you query it out, you have the ability to get it back in the format of your choice, or leave it to the database or session parameters to be your default date format.

Answer (score 2):

`DATE` is a type that contain the actual date information, the format string is just the way for us to present it in a human readable way, so as long as you follow [the format rules defined by Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/sql_elements004.htm#SQLRF00211), you can use any format to create a date with `TO_DATE()`, or to create a date time string with `TO_CHAR()`. In your case:

```
TO_DATE('2001-12-30 17:27:59', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS')
```

and insert that in your date field.

Comment: "the format is just a representation" doesn't mean anything without further clarification. A string is a representation of a date; the string itself is the representation, not the string's format. The format is also something (related to the string), but the format itself is not a representation of the date.

Comment: You're right, I made an edit, which is not very clear, but hopefully improves it.

Answer (score 0):

For the ISO format, you can simply use a `timestamp` literal:

```
insert into tablename (datecol) values (timestamp '2022-07-19 15:33:01');
```

For other formats, use to_date() or to_timestamp() with a format string (as @thatjeffsmith showed in their answer).

*UPDATE* As @mathguy pointed out in their comment, this will implicitly convert the TIMESTAMP to a DATE. To make the conversion explicit, use

```
insert into tablename(datecol) values (cast (timestamp '2022-07-19 15:33:01' as date));
```

Comment: While this will work, it is an abuse of implicit data type conversions. It would be better to wrap the timestamp literal within `cast( ... as date)` to make the conversion explicit. Also, if the OP's inputs are variables (a column in a staging table, for example), this approach won't work; date and timestamp literals only work with string **literals**, not with general string expressions.

Comment: @mathguy You're right, explicit CASTing is a good idea. Updated.